# Preg_replace_callback returns 2 values

Tags: php, regex, replace, callback, preg-replace

I have the following code but I'm not a big fan of reg exp as they are too confusing:

```
<?php
$r = '|\\*(.+)\\*|'; 
$w = '';
$s = 'hello world *copyMe* here'; 
function callbk($str){
    print_r($str);
    foreach($str as $k=>$v) {
        echo $v;
    }
}
$t = preg_replace_callback($r,'callbk',$s);

//output: Array ( [0] => *copyMe* [1] => copyMe ) *copyMe*copyMe


?>
```

my question is why is there both "***copyMe***" and "**copyMe**"?
i was hoping to get either one or the other, not both.
any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using a capturing expression `()`. If you omit the brackets you will only get `*copyMe*`.

Comment: nice one :) I thought brackets group stuff  but that did the trick ;)

Comment: Also just a quick note: it's considered best practice to write your Regexp with `/` as the delimiters, not `|`.